# How to listen "onLoad" event in <audio> tags?

Tags: javascript, frontend, onload

I've added a `<script>` tag and used `script.onload = callback` to run a callback when the element is completly renderized in document.
How can i do the same thing with `<audio>` tags?
I already try onload, but it don't works.
I already try "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onloadeddata" too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited the answer. `new Audio()` works only in Firefox currently.

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('myAudio')
audio.onloadeddata = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
audio.src = "https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3"
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
```

Comment: @LeandroCastro updated the answer. Try this one, please.

Comment: I don't want load data. I want to start the "audio" component without a src.
I just want know when my component is renderized in document. Something like "onload" on "script" tag.

Comment: @LeandroCastro onload in script tag fires once script file is downloaded by a browser. Same happens with <audio> tag. If you want to manipulate the empty <audio> tag you don't need to wait for anything, it will be ready with the rest of html.

Comment: LOL. I was confused about it... All rigth now. Thanks, man :)

Answer (score 0):

For media tags there are several events as can be found here [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events ]

You could use `onloadeddata` to run something after the media has completed loading

you could also try `oncanplay` or `oncanplaythrough` depending on whether you want a small part to buffer and load or the entire media to be loaded

`<audio oncanplaythrough="printAudioReady()" src="..." /> <span id="holder"></span>`

in JS

```
function printAudioReady() {
  document.querySelector('#holder').innerText="Audio loaded";
}
```

Comment: A details is: I don't want start my audio tags with a src. I just want print in the document and to listen when it completly loaded. Thanks

Comment: I would like something as "onload" on "script" tags

Comment: @LeandroCastro these are the alternatives for `onload` for media. I have no clue what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like when my "audio" element is completly loaded in my document.
So i will launch any callback function.
I think it's something like "onload" on "script" tag... But i don't want start "audio" component with a src.
I just want know when my element is renderized.

Comment: what do you mean completely loaded ?  if you haven't provided any src, you can very well use the window.onload since it would be the same time every element in the DOM finishes rendering including the audio tag!

Comment: It's because i'm load audio tags dynamically with javascript.
I would like have sure that audio elements is ready to use, like a script dynamically loaded for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `canplay` [media event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) listener:

```
mediaFile = new Audio('/path/to/media.mp3')
mediaFile.addEventListener('canplay', function() { console.log('Ready to play') })
```

Comment: I already try it, but don't works...
By the way, i don't want load a file in src. I want just to listen when element is renderized, similar as "onload" in script tags.